# How can I Block call by Country || Area code?

Tags: android, android-studio, call, phone-call, android-phone-call

I want know what can help for block any number calling from (Country || area code ) like +266*********

so I want  if any Incoming call from number start with +266 reject call

I want to know the sources and method of dealing with an Country number

I did not deal with receiving calls on the Android system and I do not have a background about it yet

Comment: Is this about how to use a phone? Or do you want to write an app that achieves that?

Comment: I want  write an app